What traits can I combine to make a long-lived race that matures at the human norm?
Extended Lifespan (B53) doubles the year value for all of life's milestones for each level -- at level 1, you mature at 36 instead of 18, and don't start needing aging rolls until 100, accelerating at 140 and 180 (instead of starting to age at 50, accelerating at 70 and 90).
Short Lifespan (B154) does the opposite, halving all of these milestones for each level (to a maximum of 4, which gives maturity at 1, and aging starting at 3).
But what if I want to create a race (or Ancestry, as some references now call this) that lives a long time but matures on a human scale?  Obviously, I can't combine these contradictory traits, but I'm pretty sure I remember an option at some point (perhaps in an older edition?) where the character would mature at a human rate, but then age slower.  Longevity (B66) doesn't cover it; that just reduces the rate at which attributes decline by limiting the failed HT rolls for each aging check.
I'm raising this question because it seems silly to have (for instance) an elf with Extended Lifespan 3, maturing at 72 and starting an adventuring life with no more knowledge of the world or skills than an 18 year old human.


I'm pretty sure I remember an option at some point (perhaps in an older edition?) where the character would mature at a human rate, but then age slower.

That was Early Maturation, which cost 5/level. Each level halved the age at which you reached maturity. Compendium I for Third Edition says "A race with one level of Extended Lifespan and one level of Early Maturation reaches maturity in 18 years."
GURPS Update for 4e replaces Early Maturation with the zero-point Feature (early maturation). That means you can have maturation at any age you like for no points, although this could be explained better. Update is available free of charge from Warehouse 23.

Excellent.  Now I don't have to have my long-lifers being dumb teenagers into their seventies...  And I don't have Update (I think I had a copy when 4e was fresh, but I also think I can still download it from Warehouse 23).

@ZeissIkon awww, you don’t want your not-elf parents to have to deal with over a decade of toddler years? (The real explanation for why long lived races would have so few children - it sucks spending so long raising them to be functional adults). Terrible twenties

@fyrepenguin: "Elves invented effective contraception before [they] could use fire."

Use the Early Maturation feature from GURPS Bio-Tech (page 212).

Early Maturation: You mature at the same rate as if you had Short Lifespan (p. B154) without affecting the frequency of aging rolls. This is a 0-point feature, but up to 5 levels are possible:





Level
Maturity




1
9 years


2
4 years


3
2 years


4
1 year


5
6 months





Ah, I don't have Biotech and wasn't planning to buy it (I'm building a fantasy setting), but knowing where this is in current edition is helpful.

It's also apparently in GURPS Template Toolkit 2: Races, p12, but I don't have a copy of that to confirm.
